# I'm not having setUpMapIfNeeded library in my MapsActivity.java file

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio-2.1

I posted the code snippet below as I'm unable to find the command `setUpMapIfNeeded();`. When I type the necessary command, I get red lines everywhere. Can anyone help me out with this code? Also, I'm not getting  any marker in my emulator.

I'm open to suggestions, please help me out. The min sdk version that I'm using is 17, and the android studio version is 2.1. I'm using the Googlemaps activity. I still don't understand why I'm not getting the `setUpMapIfNeeded` command and also the rest of the inbuilt code snippet.

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeJft.png)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Also after trying the missing code I'm unable to get any marker.
Whereas, wherever I have search online I'm getting this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Maps-API-v2-Usage#setup-map-if-necessary).

If you are aware of any other code, do let me know.

Comment: You have to code the setUpMapIfNeeded function, like they did on your link.

Answer (score 1):

**When you use MapsActivty, there is no need for any extra code**. All the neccessary code is generated by Android Studio itself. If you look at the tutorial, the code inside the setUpMapIfNeeded() is same as the code you have in your onCreate(). When you add the Google MapsActivty, all you need to show the map is the **Google Maps API key**. Paste the APi key in your "google_maps_api.xml"(inside values folder) and you are done. Run the application and you will get the map in your Activity.

Steps for acquiring the Google Maps API key is given in the **google_maps_api.xml in comments**.

Also if are adding your own markers, then use the following code

```
public void setMarkerOnMap(String name, LatLng l) {
    // Creating a marker
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(l);

    // Setting the title for the marker.
    // This will be displayed on taping the marker
    markerOptions.title(name);

    // Placing a marker on the touched position
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Call this function like this :

```
LatLng loc=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
String str_placeName="Place Name";
setMarkerOnMap(str_placeName,loc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setUpMapIfNeeded()` in `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```

Check this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990239/android-setupmapifneeded-gives-null-pointer-exception) on how to add markers.